# Parsing a directory of xml files and encapsulating the data in multiple arrays

Tags: python, list, xml-parsing

I found a problem I need to pars more XML files and for each file to encapsulate the data in an array of arrays.
For now, with the code I wrote, I am able to parse files and insert all parsed data into a single array.

```
for filename in filenames:  
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()

#Per estrarre dati diversi basta cambiare l'entita PADRE nei vari cicli for
for DatiGeneraliDocumento in root.iter('DatiGeneraliDocumento'):
    for FiglioDatiGeneraliDocumento in DatiGeneraliDocumento:
        if(FiglioDatiGeneraliDocumento.tag=='TipoDocumento'):
            if(FiglioDatiGeneraliDocumento.text=='TD04'):
                Concatenazione=FiglioDatiGeneraliDocumento.text + str('(NotaCredito)')
                PrimoFor.append(Concatenazione)
            else:
                Concatenazione=FiglioDatiGeneraliDocumento.text + str('(fattura)')
                PrimoFor.append(Concatenazione)
for CedentePrestatore in root.iter('CedentePrestatore'):
    for TagFiglioCedentePrestatore in CedentePrestatore:
            for TagNipoteCedentePrestatore in TagFiglioCedentePrestatore:
                for ProNipoteCedentePrestatore in TagNipoteCedentePrestatore:
                    if(ProNipoteCedentePrestatore.tag=='Denominazione'):
                        PrimoFor.append(ProNipoteCedentePrestatore.text)
for ImportoTotaleDocumento in root.iter('ImportoTotaleDocumento'):
    PrimoFor.append(ImportoTotaleDocumento.text)
    data=[PrimoFor]
    print(data)
```

The result is the following.

> [['TD01(fattura)', 'Neoss Italia S.r.l.', '2255.48', 'TD01(fattura)', 'ASTIDENTAL DI SABBIONE S.P.A.', '2717.60']]

I need this instead.

> [['TD01(fattura)', 'Neoss Italia S.r.l.','2255.48'],['TD01(fattura)', 'ASTIDENTAL DI SABBIONE S.P.A.', '2717.60']]

Can anyone help me out thanks...

Comment: `PrimoFor.append(ImportoTotaleDocumento.text)` to `PrimoFor.extend(ImportoTotaleDocumento.text)`

Comment: Unfortunately no. Extension takes the floor and divides it into char -->[['TD01(fattura)', 'Neoss Italia S.r.l.', '2', '2', '5', '5', '.', '4', '8', 'TD01(fattura)', 'ASTIDENTAL DI SABBIONE S.P.A.', '2', '7', '1', '7', '.', '6', '0']]

Comment: `PrimoFor.append([ImportoTotaleDocumento.text])` ? Your example is way to complicated. Try with a very simple xml file and a single `root.iter` to identify the problem.

Comment: @DumitruCirlan you can try with`etree` to parse xmml